# Sending Push notifications from parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been trying to send a simple push notification from one device to the other using parse and I am with no luck.

Lets say I have a twitter clone that has follow/unfollow feature, if for instance User-A begins to follow User-A all I am trying to do is notify User-A that he is now being followed by User-B

This is the simple code that I am running

```
  ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
  query.whereEqualTo("userId",  "0VZF1l5qyA");

  // Notification for Android users
  ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
  androidPush.setMessage("Your suitcase has been filled with tiny robots!");
  androidPush.setQuery(query);
  androidPush.sendInBackground();
```

Just to even make sure that it works, I hard coded the value in but still nothing is being sent. And it also not like the user that I am trying to target is not on the server.

This how my installation table looks
[image]

I think something as simple as this should just work. Or maybe I missing how push notifications work.
By the way I am able to send push notifications from the Parse web app.
FYI - I have read the entire section of [this](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) and still not getting it to work.

Addendum: I have this block of code in my main activity and modified my manifest to look like [this.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/blob/master/Android/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
    // Associate the device with a user
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("user",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    installation.put("userId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    installation.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default clients are not allowed to push notification. You  **MUST** do the following else your app wont work!! [image]